# Ring Oscillator

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator

I was wondering if it was possible to build a single stage Ring Oscillator using only one inverter. I found that it is not possible because the absence of delay, but could someone please explain me this in more details?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a CMOS inverter:

This can't work, but not because Barkhausen's criterion is violated – it just doesn't apply; this isn't a network consisting of an amplifier and a phase-shift network, it *really is an inverter connecting its input to its output*.

[image: Progression: Externally connected CMOS inverter, internally connected CMOS inverter, internal connection broken up]

Just by rearranging the external feedback to be drawn internally, then rearranging the lines, you see that the PMOS and the NMOS are but transistors with \$V_{GS}=0\$ and \$V_{DS}=0\$, respectively. So, they just act as diodes. The result is that the output remains at a constant voltage, and does not oscillate – it doesn't even have the tendency to oscillate if somehow excited with a harmonic signal.

Assuming a BJT inverter: the same argument does apply, and you just get a constant output.

Assuming any inverter that is more complex and might internally consist of multiple inverters already: well, that's not a simple single-stage ring oscillator anymore.

Comment: This is good - I was about to comment on some small detail but the details are there. Yes, this does not count as an amplifier, as there is nothing to amplify (but an inverter suitably biased can be used as an amplifier - see e.g. crystal oscillators and even NES game console audio output). And true about **unbuffered** inverters like 74HCU04 or CD4069UB. Standard **buffered** inverters like 74HC04 do have three inverters, as both input and output is buffered.

Comment: It seems like the PMOS in the diagram may be upside down? Shouldn't PMOS source be connected to VDD instead of output? This will alter the conclusion also, because Vgs is not constantly 0.

Comment: what if between the output and the input of the inverter I have an RC load? That might trigger an oscillation?

Answer (score 3):

Like other answers, I have chosen a computer model of a CMOS inverter to investigate.

It is powered from a +3.5V DC supply. When its input pin is biased about half-way (in this case at +1.726V), its output is also about half-Vdd too, and it operates as a linear inverting amplifier.
 A small AC input signal produces a larger AC output signal (about 22x larger), but at higher frequencies, output becomes smaller, until at some high frequency, output is smaller than input. Above this frequency, no oscillation is possible:
[image: open-loop inverter frequency response graph]

Of significance too, look at phase. At low frequencies, phase shift between output and input is 180 degrees, which is consistent with this device being called "inverter". At higher frequencies, phase shift drops toward zero. If it dropped to zero while gain is above *one*, we have an oscillator. But phase is still 20 degrees above zero when gain dwindles to nothing - so no way can it oscillate.

But its not far from being a potential oscillator.
For this model, one might add a little delay by feeding back output to input via an inductor, rather than a straight wire. How much (how little) inductance is required to get this inverter oscillating?[image: schematic inverter with inductor feedback]
[image: oscillating voltage vs. time graph]

An inductor too small results in no oscillation, while a much larger inductor results in robust oscillation at lower frequency. An inductor of 26 nanohenries results in small amplitude oscillation at 724 MHz, very close to maximum possible.
Would this result be possible if actually built? Most certainly not - stray capacitance and inductance would mean a much larger inductor would be needed, and oscillation would be at a much lower frequency.

Comment: Your first simlation shows the ratio Vout/Vin (magnitude and phase). May I remind you that the oscillation criterion requires a 360deg phase shift for the LOOP GAIN ?

Comment: @LvW We're in agreement - that first open-loop circuit shows 360 deg (0 deg) at about 1GHz, where gain is less than one. In this case, if you fed back output to input directly, it wouldn't oscillate. But it's not *far* from oscillating. As the 2nd circuit show, only a little wire inductance shifts phase enough to make an oscillator. No doubt, this inductor works in concert with some transistor capacitance. The model does add some internal parasitic components.

Answer (score 2):

Barkhausen stability criterion (according to Wikipedia):

1. The loop gain is equal to unity in absolute magnitude, that is, \$|\beta A|=1\$, and
2. The phase shift around the loop is zero or an integer multiple of 2π:
   \${\displaystyle \angle \beta A=2\pi n,n\in \{0,1,2,\dots \}\,.}\$

The CMOS inverter may have a complicated transfer function, but it is 180° at zero frequency and tends to 0° at infinite frequency, never attaining this value at finite frequency. It simply never satisfies Barkhausen's criterion at finite frequencies.

I built a couple simulations to illustrate this consideration. First, the small-signal AC analysis of five chained inverters. There are seven inverters in the circuit, but the two inverters, M11/M12 and M13/M14, only provide a load for the last inverter M9/M10 in the chain so that all the inverters have the identical load. The test AC voltage source is DC-uncoupled from the chain input and the last inverter output is DC-coupled to the first unverter input, so the operation point is identical for all inverters.

[image: ac-analysis]

The AC analysis plots are nearly identical for all complex voltage ratios of inverter's output vs input. We can use these plots as representatives of transfer function of the inverter. Notably, with the components chosen for our circuit, TF starts from +28db (magnitude) and 180° (phase) at small frequency and tends to -12dB and 0° at large frequencies, never running outside these limits:

[image: 1inv-ac]

The total transfer functions of the chain with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 inverters:

[image: ring-5invs-ac]

All plots are scaled variants of the inverter plot, with the starting phase alternating between odd- and even-numbered chains. The one-inverter chain has TF that starts from +28dB/180° and tends to -12dB/0°, the two-inverter chain has TF that starts from +56dB/0° and tends to -24dB/-360° (2x) and so on up to the five-inverter chain with TF that starts from +140dB/180° and tends to -60dB/-720° (5x).

The inverter TF phase never crosses 0° or an integer multiple of 2π (+/-360°, +/-720°, ...), only tends to 0°. This crossing is a necessary condition of the Barkhausen stability criterion, item 2, so one cannot build an oscillator with one inverter of the kind we used here, the feedback being a bare wire, although it can be made with inverters buffered at the input and the output (3-inverter chains) or with an inductive feedback.

TF phase plots of multiple-inverter chains, both odd- and even-numbered, are crossing multiples of 2π. Odd-numbered chains become ring oscillators with the output connected to the input:

[image: ringosc5]

[image: ringosc3]

An even-numbered chain cannot become a ring oscillator:

[image: ringosc4]

To relate these observations with the Barkhausen criterion, notice that the criterion determines only when a **linear** electronic circuit will oscillate. In the ring oscillator problem, this means that the criterion works when the small signal analysis is performed on the circuit at the operation point. For many circuits (ring oscillators inluding) the item 1 of the Barkhausen stability criterion is difficult to comply precisely, and oscillations become more than hardly sustainable. Starting as the small-signal perturbations of the unstable state at the operation point, these oscillations are growing, their increase in amplitude limited only by non-linear behavior of the circuit -- say, the amplitude growth is limited by the supply voltage. For odd-numbered chains there is no equilibrium states except the unstable operation point, and oscillations never stop. Even-numbered chains have two stable equilibria and the circuit stops at this states. A single inverter with its input and its output connected does not oscillate, because the Barkhausen stability criterion, item 2, does not hold:

[image: ringosc1]

Bearing in mind evident simplicity of the explanation where the inverter is re-arranged to become two totem-pole-arranged diode-connected transistors, why should we address the Barkhausen stability criterion? Why *reductio ad diodum* (pseudo Latin) is not enough?

First, the Barkhausen criterion does apply notwithstanding any circuit transformation. In the small-signal approximation, *an inverter with its input and its output connected* is still an **amplifier** with its input and its output connected. The phase-shift network feedback is not required to necessarily be sophisticated; in particular, it can be a bare wire, β = 1. The Barkhausen criterion can be applied.

Then, even if we transform the inverter with the feedback into two totem-pole diode-connected transistors, we does not arrive at the solution. Instead of one amplifier with the bare-wire feedback there would be two totem-pole-arranged amplifiers, each with its bare-wire feedback, because the diode-connected transistor is the voltage controlled current source (amplifier) with its output (drain) and its input (gate) connected.

So why this reductio-ad-diodum solution is seemingly attractive? Because we know that ordinary diodes, like 1N4148, connected in this way, do not generate. But we know, too, that ordinary unbuffered inverters with the bare-wire feedback also do not generate. And the fact that the diode-connected transistor does not oscillate in circuits has also yet to be proved, because the transistor, even diode-connected, is not a diode, only their DC-sweep characteristics are alike. And diodes may vary -- some even have negative differential resistance in its current–voltage characteristic (I know that ours is not the case).

Summing up, for CMOS unbuffered inverters the TF phase starts from 180° and tends to 0°, never crossing 0° or an integer multiple of 2π. This behaviour does not comply with the Barkhausen stability criterion, item 2, a necessary condition for oscillation, and the oscillations never start from the equilibrium state of connected inverter's input and output.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider that the inverter is biased at the region where it behaves as an amplifier (i.e., INP = OUT). There is only 1 pole here (RDS parallel to Cout). A single pole can provide a max phase shift of 90 deg. Now, the inverter itself gives a 180 deg phase shift. So, adding the two, we get a max phase shift of 270 deg from INP to OUT. According to Barkhausen's criteria, one criteria is that we need 360 phase shift or multiples of it from INP to OUT at some frequency f for the system to oscillate at that frequency which is not possible from a single inverter. The gain-phase plot of a single inverter is shown below. It will never go to 0 deg.

[image]

Comment: This argument *must* be false, because by that logic *no* ring oscillator would ever function, because an inverter has a 180° phase shift at every frequency. You could then only build ring oscillators with **even** numbers of inverters, whereas these are the rings of inverters that do **not** oscillate, but converge quickly to one stable configuration (where HIGH/LOW just alternate through the chain, but stay static).

Comment: I never claimed that having 360 deg phase shift is sufficient for making the ring oscillator oscillate. It is one of the conditions. Even number of inverters do not oscillate because there is no gain in the loop when all the inverters are in a stable configuration (i.e., HIGH/LOW alternate).

Comment: sai, but the point is that you're applying a necessary criterion to something it doesn't apply to.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I agree with your idea of looking at the single inverter as 2 diodes in series but this idea of using Barkhausen's criteria is also correct. It is like saying a single pole amplifier in a negative feedback loop is stable and can never oscillate.

Comment: I fully agree with that a single pole amplifier in direct feedback, as you correctly say and show, cannot oscillate. 100% agreeing with you! But this is not a single pole amplifier, because you cannot argue with "we operate the inverter close to its linear range and hence can treat it as an amplifier with some phase close to 180°" if you're looking for stable oscillation – that would inherently need a larger amplitude than the linear range would cover. It's really not that I disagree with Barkhausen or you – just that Barkhausen doesn't apply to this system.

Comment: If you will, the property "amplifier" depends on the system's output *not* being physically wired to its input.

Comment: Even in a 3 stage ring, we connect the output to the input physically. There we do use barkhausen criteria and find the gain required and frequency based on the same. I am trying to understand your point as to why that criteria doesn't apply here but I am not able to follow inspite of your explanation.

Comment: yes, I was confused by that fact as well at first, but then I realized that the gain of a single stage depends on the output *not* driving the input. The gain just manifests when driving a load that does not instantaneously pull the input in the opposite direction! Think of an inverting audio amplifier that consists of a transistor with negative feedback to achieve a (somewhat) stable gain: That feedback sets a gain, it's not part of an external feedback path where the output *directly* affects the input. Same is true here! Only through the "isolation" of a following stage could this be …

Comment: …considered an independent amplifier.